# Как в Laravel не принимать get-параметры при нажатии кнопки «назад» в браузере?

Tags: php, laravel

Уважаемые специалисты! Подскажите, как в Laravel не принимать get-параметры при нажатии назад в браузере? Т.е. когда человек заходит на страницу и нажимает кнопку у меня запускается функция
`public function CreateMeetingToFreeManadger(Request $request) { //...toDO }`
но проблема в том, что когда он нажимает назад, функция снова запускается, хотя мне это не нужно.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: laravel и рhp в целом мне кажется здесь не причем. Они выполняют то что им послал браузер. Вам нужно менять параметры этого get-запроса отлавливая в js cобытие popstate (которое как раз срабатывает при нажатии кнопки назад в браузере). Таким образом запрос будет проходить штатно если это не нажатие кнопки и иметь дополнительный параметр при нажатии и уже потом на сервере в Вашей функции можно поставить условие (если это был простой переход, выполнять, если нет, не выполнять) Конечно может есть и более элегантный способ это решить, но сомневаюсь честно сказать что есть...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функция может сама учитывать повторный запрос.
Варианты:

- сделать создание пост-ом -- https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get
- сделать, чтоб адрес изначально содержал случайный UUID митинга, и проверять, что с таким UUID уже создан
- проставлять куки с UUID митинга при создании